# Check if ADO token has expired for nuget feed authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-devops, nuget

Currently anytime our build runs locally, we first remove the configured ADO nuget feed:

```
nuget sources remove -name OurFeed
```

We then use the Credential Provider to give us a new token, and re-create the feed with this:

```
$feed = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ourfeed/_packaging/ourfeed/nuget/v3/index.json"
$creds = (& CredentialProvider.VSS.exe -U $feed | ConvertFrom-Json)
Exec { & nuget sources add -name OurFeed -username $creds.Username -password $creds.Password -storepasswordincleartext -source $feed }
```

Of course it's quite inefficient to do this **every** build. The reason we do it is because we need to ensure the ADO authentication token hasn't expired before building our projects.

Is there some clever way we can (very quickly) check if the feed token is still valid before doing this?

Comment: If you install the credential provider such that NuGet can discover it itself, then you don't need to put the token in your nuget.config, NuGet will automatically use the credential provider to get the token on-demand.

Comment: @zivkan Could you please elaborate on this, how is NuGet able to discover the CredentialProvider itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some clever way we can (very quickly) check if the feed token is still valid before doing this?

We could use the REST API [Personal Access Tokens - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadmin/personal%20access%20tokens/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to lists of all the session token details of the personal access tokens (PATs) for a particular user:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/tokenadmin/personalaccesstokens/{subjectDescriptor}?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

To get the parameter `subjectDescriptor`, we could use following REST API with the **PAT** of the particular user, it will return the `subjectDescriptor` of that particular user:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{ORGANISATION_NAME}/_apis/connectionData
```

[image]

Then use the Personal Access Tokens - List to get the detail info about the PAT:

[image]

In this case, we could create a script to verify the `validTo` value.